# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_{x}^{x+l} f(s) ds.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = m,$$
for some $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $l > 0$ be fixed. Find 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_{x}^{x+l} f(s) ds.$$

I tried rewriting the limit as
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_{0}^{x+l} f(s) ds - \int_{0}^{x} f(s) ds$$ 
and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} F'(x) = m$, but this did not help much.

Any hints?

Comment: If $f(s)$ were the constant function $m$, what would $\int_x^{x+l}f(s)ds$ be? So as $f$ approaches $m$, we should be in basically the same situation. You just need to figure out how much you miss by replacing $f$ by the constant $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as
$$
\int_0^l f(x+s)\,ds
$$
and argue that you can exchange the integral and the limit.

Comment: What allows us to interchange the limit and the integral?

Comment: Uniform convergence. Or you could directly bound $\int_0^l(f(x+s)-m)\,ds$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: By the mean value theorem, for any $x>0$ there always exists some $c \in (x,x+l)$ such that $$l\cdot f(c)= \int_x^{x+l} f(x)dx$$

Comment: But we don't know $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $x_0$ such that $x\ge x_0$ implies $m-\epsilon<f(x) < m+\epsilon.$ Thus for $x\ge x_0,$

$$\int_x^{x+1} (m-\epsilon)\, dt \le \int_x^{x+1} f(t)\, dt \le \int_x^{x+1} (m+\epsilon)\, dt.$$